# CustomCursorLoader class does not refresh cursor on button click

Tags: android, sqlite

I have written a program to add mobile no into my sqlite database on a button click which is working properly , I am also using a listview to show the data added for which I am using a CustomCursorLoader class to query my results .

The problem which I am facing is , suppose I have nothing in my database so the cursor count is 0 but when I insert a data for the first time , the cursor count should become 1 but it shows 0 , and then again when I insert another data at that moment i am getting cursor count as 1 but the data which was previously inserted is being shown in the listview

Posting my code

```
public class Home_Page extends Activity implements 
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    DriverStatusAdapter driverStatusAdapter;
    ListView listDriverId;
    private static final int URL_LOADER = 0;
    CustomCursorLoader loader = null;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    try{
        dbListHelper = new DriverSqliteHelper(getBaseContext());
        dbListHelper.open(getBaseContext());
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String[] columns = new String[] 
    {DriverSqliteHelper.DbListHelper.DRIVER_USER_ID};
    int[] to = new int[]{R.id.DriverId};
    driverStatusAdapter = new DriverStatusAdapter(getBaseContext(),
    R.layout.view_userid_item,null,columns,to,0);
    listDriverId = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.driverIDList);
    listDriverId.setAdapter(driverStatusAdapter);
    registerForContextMenu(listDriverId);
    Log.i("LoaderManager", "Started on activity start");
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, Home_Page.this);

    txtAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        String userId = edtUserId.getText().toString();
        if (userId.equals("")) 
            {
              Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Please  
              enter user id", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
              View sbView = snackbar.getView();
              TextView textView = (TextView)  
              sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.
              snackbar_text);
              snackbar.show();
            }
        else{
              sendUserStatus(); ///// method to send mobile no to server
              //// if status received from server is ok then i am inserting    
              ////the data into the database
              Log.i("LoaderManager", "Restarted on button click");
              getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, Home_Page.this);
            }

 @Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
    switch (i){
        case URL_LOADER:
            Log.i("Case URL Loader", "Custom Cursor Loader called");
            loader = new CustomCursorLoader(getBaseContext());
            return loader;
        default:
            Log.i("Case default", "Default Case called");
            return null;
    }

}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    Log.i("LoaderManager", "Finished load entry... - Cursor: " + 
    cursor.getCount());
    this.loader = (CustomCursorLoader)loader;
    driverStatusAdapter.changeCursor(cursor);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    Log.i("LoaderManager", "Resetting loader...");
    driverStatusAdapter.changeCursor(null);
}
```

}

CustomCursorLoader.java

```
public class CustomCursorLoader extends CursorLoader{

Context context;
DriverSqliteHelper driverSqliteHelper;
Cursor cursor;

public CustomCursorLoader(Context context) {
    super(context);
    try {
        driverSqliteHelper = new DriverSqliteHelper(context);
        driverSqliteHelper.open(context);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Cursor loadInBackground(){
    cursor = driverSqliteHelper.getDriverStatus();
    return cursor;
}
```

}

My Logcat

I/LoaderManager﹕ Started on activity start
I/Case URL Loader﹕ Custom Cursor Loader called
I/LoaderManager﹕ Finished load entry... - Cursor: 2

********on my first button click ********

I/LoaderManager﹕ Restarted on button click
I/Case URL Loader﹕ Custom Cursor Loader called
I/LoaderManager﹕ Finished load entry... - Cursor: 2

********* on my second button click ********

I/LoaderManager﹕ Restarted on button click
I/Case URL Loader﹕ Custom Cursor Loader called
I/LoaderManager﹕ Finished load entry... - Cursor: 3

I want my cursor count to change on first button click itself , can anyone suggest me what changes do i need to make ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have found the solution myself , i put the  getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, Home_Page.this); inside sendUserStatus() method where i am also inserting the data.
Now the cursor count is incrementing and the listview is also getting updated automcatically